# C# Type Object Pointer

Tags: c#, object, types, heap-memory, clr

I have read about this topic in CLR C# but theres something im wondering about.

It is said that an instance of a class only stores its fields, a type object pointer (pointing to its type object) and its sync block index in the heap. the type object itself also has a type object pointer. so at which object does the type object`s type object pointer point to? shouldnt be all important data and metadata for the class already be in the type object itself?

hope you get my point its quite confusing ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Jeffrey Richter's "CLR via C#" book, Chapter 4 "Type Fundamentals":

> Of course, the **system.type** object is an object itself and therefore
>   it also has a type object pointer member in it, and it is logical to
>   ask what this member refers to. It refers to itself because the **system.type** object is itself an "instance" of a type object.

So there you go: It points to itself (as you probably expected).

Comment: In the book said the CLR use this type object pointer to manage the object. Is this the same pointer created on the stack to reference an object on the heap?